# How to incorporate Google Maps on Crystal Report

Tags: google-maps, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I would like to know how to incorporate Google Maps onto crystal reports.
Currently my data presents only LAT/LONG presented in this format

> 0310403N 0810401W

I have been able to incorporate Google Maps using street addresses just fine, only problem is the others I am trying to demonstrate are moving objects that is why they are presented using LAT/LONG.

This is what I currently have to show the street addresses

```
//Image URL WhilePrintingRecords; StringVar Markers; "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap" & "?center=" & {@Address CityState} & "&size=512x512" & "&visual_refresh=true" & "&maptype=satellite" & Markers & "&sensor=false"
```

Comment: I figured it out! THx

Comment: care to share your solution? You should post your answer and mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a formula field using your LAT/LONG coordinates in DMM/DMS format
in my case it was not in a correct format so I had to adjust it 
here

```
totext(ROUND(ROUND(tonumber(mid({DRIVER.POSLAT},2,2)),5)+ ROUND((tonumber(mid({DRIVER.POSLAT},4,2))/60),5)+ ROUND((tonumber(mid({DRIVER.POSLAT},6,2))/3600),5),5),5)+", -"&

totext(tonumber(mid({DRIVER.POSLONG},2,2))+ (tonumber(mid({DRIVER.POSLONG},4,2))/60)+ (tonumber(mid({DRIVER.POSLONG},6,2))/3600),5)
```

Then go to design mode and drag a picture in the detail area
right click and select format editor
go to the picture tab
select graphic location 
and paste this in here

```
//Image URL
"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap" &
"?center=" & {@LOC} &
"&zoom=14&size=545x355" &
"&visual_refresh=true" &
"&maptype=hybrid" &
"&markers=" & {@LOC}
```

"LOC" is the name of the formula field, name it whatever you want.